# How to convert datetime by applying UTC offset in php?

Tags: php, datetime, cakephp, utc

how to apply the UTC in datestring in php?

Sample Code:

```
$sample_date = "2016-01-01 01:00:00 +01:00";
```

How to convert this one to:

```
$sample_date = "2016-01-01 02:00:00";
```

Comment: Strange request... What do you need that for? `2016-01-01 01:00:00 +01:00` == `2016-01-01 02:00:00 +02:00` and not `2016-01-01 02:00:00`...

Comment: @Glavić Yes, your point is true but what I wanted is to apply the UTC offset (`+01:00`) to the main datetime which is `2016-01-01 01:00:00)`

Comment: So you are saying that `2016-01-01 01:00:00` is UTC = `+00:00`? Because `+01:00` cannot be UTC...

Answer (score 0):

One way to be to write a custom function as below:

```
$thisDate = "2016-01-01 01:00:00 +01:00";
$seperated = explode('+', $thisDate);

$splitHours = explode(':',$seperated[1]);

$hoursToAdd = isset($splitHours[0]) ? (($splitHours[0]!='0' && $splitHours[0]!='00') ? $splitHours[0].'H' : '') : '';
$minutesToAdd = isset($splitHours[1]) ?  (($splitHours[1]!='0' && $splitHours[1]!='00') ? $splitHours[1].'S' : '') : '';

$addtionString = ($splitHours[0]!='' || $splitHours[1]!='') ? 'PT'.$hoursToAdd.$minutesToAdd : '';
$date = new DateTime($seperated[0]);
if($addtionString != '') {
    $date->add(new DateInterval($addtionString));

}
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
```

Can't think of any built in function which already does it..

Comment: Thanks, but it returns `2016-01-01 08:00:00` instead of `2016-01-01 02:00:00` same also as converting `+01:00` to seconds and add, still output is `2016-01-01 08:00:00`. I don't know why is that.

Comment: sorry just misunderstood your question..have a look at updated ans.

Answer (score 0):

You will get result below

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',(strtotime($sample_date)+3600));                    
echo $date;
```